# Firebase phone authentication shows exception when activity resumes: "The sms code has expired. Please re-send the verification code to try again."

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase phone authentication for verifying phone number. But, there is an issue **when I try to switch any other app or just press the home button in the middle of the process is going on, i.e in between the process has started and ended.** Even if the OTP is correct and the time is not expired it always shows the `FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException` with the following message.

> The SMS code has expired. Please re-send the verification code to try again.

Previously, I found out that when the activity pause and resumes back in the middle of the process is going on, the authentication process (either verification of OTP or sending the OTP ) stops and it does not resume. So, for that, I manually started the process. Now, the process starts but it returns the above exception always.

By using the method `resumeProcess()` in on Resume. Now, `receiveOTP()` works fine. but veirifcation of OTP has still the issue. (as explined just above).

I am using a dialog for phone authentication.

The code I've written for phone authentication and for the issue is as follows.

To resume the process manually, which was stopped on pause. I am using `resumeProcess()` method in `onResume()`.

In fragment's `onResume()`

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (phoneAuthDialog != null && phoneAuthDialog.isShowing()) {
        phoneAuthDialog.resumeProcess();
    }
}
```

And, In dialog...

```
public void resumeProcess(){
    if(isReceivingOtpSms){
        receiveOtp(phoneNumber,null);
    }

    if(isVerifyingOtp){
        verifyOtp();
    }
}
```

for receiving OTP.

```
private void receiveOtp(String phoneNumber,PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
    if (connectionDetector != null && connectionDetector.isConnectingToInternet()) {

        setPhoneVerificationCallback();
        isReceivingOtpSms =true;
        showProgress();

        //for receiving otp for the first time
        if(forceResendingToken==null){
            PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                    phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
                    60,                 // Timeout duration
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                    activity,               // Activity (for callback binding)
                    mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
        }

        //for resending otp
        else {
            PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                    phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
                    60,                 // Timeout duration
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                    activity,               // Activity (for callback binding)
                    mCallbacks,          // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
                    forceResendingToken);
        }

    } else
        showToast(activity, Constants.MESSAGE_NO_CONNECTION);
}
```

The `setPhoneVerificationCallback()` method is used for handling verificationcallback.

```
private void setPhoneVerificationCallback() {
    mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
            hideProgress();               //to hide progressbar.
            isReceivingOtpSms=false;
            //some ui process....
            verifyCredentials(phoneAuthCredential); 
        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut(String s) {
            super.onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            hideProgress();
            isReceivingOtpSms=false;

            if (e instanceof FirebaseNetworkException) {
                showToast(activity, activity.getString(R.string.err_noconnection_message));
            } else if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                showToast(activity, "Incorrect phone number format. Check your mobile number and country code twice.");
            } else {
                showToast(activity, e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String verificationId, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
            super.onCodeSent(verificationId, forceResendingToken);
            hideProgress();
            isReceivingOtpSms=false;
            PhoneAuthDialogRefactored.this.verificationId = verificationId;
            PhoneAuthDialogRefactored.this.forceResendingToken = forceResendingToken;

            //some ui process ...

            showToast(activity, "code sent to your number");
        }
    };
}
```

The `verifyOTP()` method

```
private void verifyOtp() {
    String otp = etOtp.getText().toString().trim();
    if (otp.length() == 6) {

        if (connectionDetector != null && connectionDetector.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            if (verificationId != null) {
                Log.e("Verification ID : ", verificationId);
                PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, otp.trim());
                verifyCredentials(credential);
            } else {
                showToast(activity, "Please wait for a while! the code is not sent yet.");
            }
        } else {
            showToast(activity, activity.getString(R.string.err_noconnection_message));
        }
    } else {
        errOtp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        errOtp.setText(activity.getString(R.string.err_required));
    }
}
```

The `verifyCredentials` method verifies the OTP is correct or not.

```
private void verifyCredentials(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    isVerifyingOtp=true;
    showProgress();

    if (activity != null) {
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(activity, task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        hideProgress();
                        isVerifyingOtp=false;
                        //some ui process...

                    } else {
                        // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                        hideProgress();
                        isVerifyingOtp=false;
                        Log.w("Phone authentication", "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            // The verification code entered was invalid

                            Exception exception=task.getException();
                            if(exception.getMessage().equals("The sms code has expired. Please re-send the verification code to try again.")){
                                showToast(activity,exception.getMessage());
                                errOtp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                errOtp.setText(activity.getString(R.string.err_expired_code));
                            }
                            else {
                                errOtp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                errOtp.setText(activity.getString(R.string.err_wrong_otp));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Please help me with the issue and feel free to ask if my question is not clear. The major issue is

> When even the OTP is correct and the time is not expired. It still shows the code has expired. and it happens only in the case when we pasue and resume back to the activity. in the middle of a process. (by in the middle of a process I mean, the verification process has started but before it completes its verification process (success or failure) I press switch to another app and come back to the app)

Comment: what happen if you stay on the same activity and enter the code?

Comment: @RahulKhurana It works perfectly. In that case. The issue is only when we minimize the app or we press home button or similar cases.

Comment: just put a check to **mCallbacks** to see if it is null. and if it is not null then don't reset it

Comment: @RahulKhurana it didn't work.

Comment: can you post your full code here ?

Comment: @RahulKhurana The code I've posted covers all the things related to phone auth. the other code contains UI related process. such as hiding and showing different ui components. etc...

Comment: Is your dialog got closed when activity is paused?

Comment: @RahulKhurana No. I am not closing it.

Comment: does the boolean values remained same ?? as in isReceivingOtpSms?

Comment: @RahulKhurana the values are true when the process is starting and on completion (success or failure), I am assigning them as false. As you can see in `reciveOtp()` `isReceivingOtpSms` is set to true and in `verificationCompleted()` or in `codeSent` it is set to false. In the same manner in `verifyCredentials` `isVerifyingOtp` is set to true in the beginning and on completion of the task it is set to false.

Comment: @Riddhi I'm facing the same error. Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Riddhi I think the problem is with the verificationId which you are sending at the time of verification. The Code seems to be good. I had the same problem previously when I am sending the verificationId.

```
public class OtpVerificationActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText mobileNumber,otpText;
    Button sendOtp,verifyOtp;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    String codeSent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_otp_verification);

        mobileNumber = findViewById(R.id.mobileNumber);
        otpText = findViewById(R.id.otpText);
        sendOtp = findViewById(R.id.sendOtp);
        verifyOtp = findViewById(R.id.verifyOtp);

        sendOtp.setOnClickListener(this);
        verifyOtp.setOnClickListener(this);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.sendOtp:

                sendVerificationCode();
                break;

            case R.id.verifyOtp:

                verifyCodeSent();
                break;
        }

    }

    private void verifyCodeSent() {

        String code = otpText.getText().toString();
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(codeSent,code);
        signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
    }

    private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d("verifyCode", "signInWithCredential:success");

                            Toast.makeText(OtpVerificationActivity.this, "Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                            // ...
                        } else {
                            // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                            Log.w("verifyCode", "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                                // The verification code entered was invalid
                                Toast.makeText(OtpVerificationActivity.this, ""+task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void sendVerificationCode() {

        String phoneNumber = mobileNumber.getText().toString();

        if (phoneNumber.isEmpty()){
            mobileNumber.setError("mobile number cannot be empty");
            mobileNumber.requestFocus();
        }

        if (phoneNumber.length() < 10){
            mobileNumber.setError("Please enter a valid phone");
            mobileNumber.requestFocus();
        }

        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                "+91" + phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify (I hardcoded it only for Indian Mobile numbers).
                60,                 // Timeout duration
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
                mCallbacks);
    }

    PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
            super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);

            codeSent = s;
        }
    };
}
```

I hope it works for you. Could you get back to me after you check this code?

Comment: thanks for trying to help me. but `verificationId` is just another name of the variable `s` you have used in `codesent` method. and you are also using the same code which I am using. And as I said in my question, that in the normal case it works fine